# Is there a way to share memory allocated outside a shared segment between processes?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a `char[1024]` **already** allocated on the heap. Is there a way to share the allocated array via `boost::interprocess` or any other way without requiring it to be allocated on a shared memory segment first? In other words, I need a way to create the shared memory object **after** the array has been created, **from** the array itself.

This won't work for some unkown reasons:

```
char* mem = new char[1024];
shared_memory_object shm (create_only, "id", read_write);
shm.truncate(1024);
mapped_region region(shm, read_write, 0, 1024, mem);
```

the `mapped_region` constructor throws an `interprocess_exception e` , which does not give useful informations:

```
cout << "Error: " << e.get_error_code() << ' ' << e.get_native_error() << ' ' << e.what() << "\n";
```

which prints:

```
Error: 1 0
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the IPC but it's more C than C++
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html

Comment: I prefer using boost if possible

Comment: The key thing in the problem is that I want to share the memory block *after* its allocation on the heap.

Comment: Like a [fixed address mapping](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region.mapped_region_fixed_address_mapping)? It tells the system to map the shared memory on a fixed address, like on your array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it does not work, see my edits